# How to find number rise within 1 hour in Excell?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have numbers logged over the period of time. In one column, lets call it A there is a time in seconds from 0 to 10000, in the column B temperature logged accordingly to the time. Temperature usually rising from low to high.

How can I find what temperature is when it is rising no more than 2 degrees an hour?

I can't upload images to make it clear, because I'm the new user, but to find the temperature I draw a temperature curve and 2 degrees per hour line. When that line touch the temperature curve I have point where temperature rise is no more than 2 degrees. So if my temperature started from 24.12°C and it rises quick within first minutes up to 30.25°C and then rise slowed down until temperature stabilized and stayed constant 40°C.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Please **[edit]** your question to include what you have researched and tried so far.

Comment: It isn't clear what you are looking for.  Are you describing a situation where temperature rises quickly and then levels off and you want to find the temperature at the inflection point based on cumulative rise over the previous hour?  Are the recordings "continuous" (there is a reading every second or some fixed interval rather than varying gaps between readings)?

Comment: Depending on the time increments between readings, there might not be a reading exactly an hour before, which complicates things.  Are you talking about 2 degrees an hour as an actual desired 1 hour interval or a rate (any reading where the difference compared to the previous reading equates to a rate of not more than 2 degrees per hour)?  Also readings have some level of noise.  Are you talking about comparing actual readings or basing the calculation on smoothed values (a curve that the values describe)?

Comment: How do you create the temperature curve?  Is this just by eye or does it follow a common type of curve and you do a curve fit or graph the data and add a non-linear trend line (if so, what type of curve)?

Comment: I do curve from logged data in excel by using scatter chart type.

Comment: And do you have Excel fit a non-linear trendline?  If so, there is an option to display the trendline equation, in which case it becomes a math problem to solve the simultaneous equations or solve it with successive approximations.  I'll have to think about how to implement this in Excel.  What type of curve do you find fits the data?

Comment: Using the trendline equation and the 2 deg/hr line equation, you can use this: http://chandoo.org/wp/2013/09/19/how-to-solve-an-equation-in-excel/.  It will take some investigation to see if the trendline parameters can be directly referenced, which would let you automate the calculation.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that you can adapt.  Column **A** contains time  in seconds.  Column **B** contains the temperature.  In **C3** enter:

```
=(B3-B2)*3600
```

and copy down.  This is the temperature rise in degrees per hour and **assumes the data is one second per row.**  *(you will need a different formula if the interval is not one second)*

In another cell, enter:

```
=INDEX(B3:B100,MATCH(2,C3:C100,-1)+1)
```

Here is an example:

[image]

Comment: The temperature is logged every second for about 3 or 4 hours and it's floating up and down like 1s-24.2 2s-24.2 3s-24.2 4s-24.0 5s-24.4 and so on, so I entered your suggested formulas there, but got an error #N/A in index raw. And my rate column readings is like -36 0 72 396 504 726 -72 425 and so on.

Comment: I liked your idea of finding 2 degrees rise, but problem is not with your idea but with my data. So what I did is, I've averaged temperatures every minute to make them more constant and then averaged the rate too, so now I'm getting the temperature I want by using your method. THANK YOU very much!!!

Comment: @Tusitas I am glad you were able to adapt at least part of my suggestion.......have a great day!